# Cache default method of spring data repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cache

I am using spring data and cache.

Is there any way to put cache on default methods of repository (findOne...) without to redeclare those methods in the interface, that we create?

```
public interface AccountOperationRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountOperation, Long>{
    @Cacheable(value = "myCache")
    AccountOperation findOne(Long id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you own dao, for basic information:

```
public interface CachedDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

@Cacheable(value = "cacheValue1")
T findOne(ID id);

@Cacheable(value = "cacheValue2")
List<T> findAll();

@Cacheable(value = "cacheValue3")
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
//Evict because you want to modify value
@CacheEvict(value = "cacheValue4", allEntries = true)
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
//the same with delete
@CacheEvict(value = "cacheValue5", allEntries = true)
void delete(ID id);
}
```

You need to search a little more, hope it helps.

Comment: every object will use the same name for the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I have used it like this in a spring data repository

```
    @Cacheable(value = "accountIds",sync = true)
    default List<AccountDetailDTO> getAccountIds() {
       findById();
    }
```